# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "" : Error

Tags: java, android, parseint

I am doing some calculation but unable to parse a string into int or even in float.I searched for solution and i read it somewhere there must be a empty string but i checked my editText using

```
log.v("Valuee",e1.getText().toString());
```

and its print the values prove that string is not empty.. 
What i am missing ?

Here is **logcat**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.farrukh.bmi/com.example.farrukh.bmi.Main2Activity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
>      at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
>      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
>      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
>      at com.example.farrukh.bmi.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:31)
>      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
>      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

Here is **MainActivity.java**

```
 public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

          final   Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
          final   EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
          final   TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
          final  String height = e1.getText().toString();


          final int a = Integer.parseInt(height); //got error while parsing

     b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                 //   Log.v("EditText",e1.getText().toString());

                }
            });


        }


    }
```

Here is **activity.xml**

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="132dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="CLICK"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/button"/>

<EditText
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="#3b9ff0" />
```

Comment: Its because of there is no value in e1. First on click do validation and then convert to interger

Comment: e1 contains blank text, hence the issue

Comment: you need to use gettext() inside onclick()

Comment: @jipr311 OP having problem with `NumberFormatException` not null pointer exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put these lines inside `onClick()`

```
final  String height = e1.getText().toString();
final int a = Integer.parseInt(height);
```

You are fetching value of `e1` in `onCreate()`, while you want it when user click on button

Also need to check whether height is having any value or not, check [Stuluske's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34947241/3134215) answer for this

Comment: Possibly because you did not consider that height may not be a number. However, I upvoted this answer, because it is useless to use `getText()` during `onCreate()`.

Comment: @LordAnomander ohh yes, i forget that point, will update my answer

Comment: Thankyou :) I just forget it

Answer (score 12):

You are trying to parse an empty String ( "" ) to a numerical value, but "" is not a numerical value.

Make sure you set it to required, or check for emptiness before trying to parse it.

```
final int a = !height.equals("")?Integer.parseInt(height) : 0;
```

for instance.

EDIT:

If you have added spaces, so it would be "  ";

```
height = height.trim();
final int a = !height.equals("")?Integer.parseInt(height) : 0;
```

should do the trick.

Comment: what if I have added 2 spaces

Comment: I've added the response to that in the answer.

Comment: This will avoid the crash, yes, but does not allow OP to actually read the entered value since the code runs too early.

Comment: The gettting value must be in onClick Its because its triggered when you click a button after entering some value to the text field. and op can also add a check !TextUtils.isEmpty(string)

Comment: True, then again, the question is about the NumberFormatException.

Comment: Thanks man for the explanation :) I just forget to put it in onclick function

Answer (score 2):

There's no value yet when `onCreate()` runs. Move the `getText()` and `parseInt()` inside your click listener to read and parse the value when you have entered something.

Answer (score 0):

put a check before doing Integer.parseInt like

```
final int a = (height == null || height.trim().equal("") ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(height));
```

Also you need to add this code for getting the height value from edittext inside onclick listener as when in OnCreate control will not have any value apart you set some default value in layout.xml as it is just created

Answer (score 0):

you should get the values inside a method so that your app does not try to assign the values immediatly you are creating them check below how am doing it using kotlin

```
     myresult = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtresult)
     val1 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.valone)
     val2 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.valtwo)
```

after getting the field use method as below

```
    fun calculate() : Int {

        var value1 = Integer.parseInt(val1.text.toString())
        var value2 = val2.text.toString().toInt()
        var result : Int

        when (opType){

            "+" ->{result = value1 + value2
                    return result
                 }
            "-" ->{result = value1 - value2
                return result
            }
            "*" -> {result = value1 * value2
                return result
            }
            "/" -> {result = value1 / value2
                return result
            } else -> result = 20

        }

        return result
    }

     btn.setOnClickListener{

        println(calculate().toString())
        myresult.text = calculate().toString()


    }
```

for those moving to kotlin and finding the same error I hope this code will help you